# How to modify a text inputbox so that it accepts only certain characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've an input box in which I only want to allow `0-9`, `(`, `)`, `-`, `.`, and (space) characters. After researching and picking up code from different tutorials, I managed to (I think) come up with the required regex pattern.

But it isn't working and always returning `false` even if the character typed is one from the above. The code that I've with me is as follows:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/[0-9.\(\)\b\ -]/", "gi");
if(regex.test(str)){
    return true;
} else {
    console.log('failed');
    return false;
}
```

I'm having `failed` printed in the console every single time. What am I missing here?

EDIT: [**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pI9oS7/2) (It seems to be working here)
EDIT2: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/czkomau9/)

**UPDATE:**

I think my question is being misinterpreted here. I probably didn't do a good job at describing my use case. Well here it is then:

In my textbox, I only want to allow the above mentioned characters. So if a user types "23a" in the textbox, it should only allow "23" and "a" shouldn't be allowed to be typed

Comment: @Uchiha The logic is correct, but the character is still getting typed in the textbox, right? I want to disable that...

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsisodia91/czkomau9/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new RegExp()` is superfluous here, just use regex literal notation (see note #2 below).

You want to anchor the expression to the beginning (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the string, to make sure it applies to the entire string. That's what you have tried to accomplish with `g`, but that is not what `g` does.

The `i` (case-insensitive) modifier is not necessary either, the pattern does not contain letters.

```js
function isValidChar(str) {
    return /^[0-9.() -]$/.test(str);
}

$(function(){
    $('#p_zip').on('keypress', function (e) {
        return isValidChar(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="p_zip">
```

---

Here is a version that works entirely without regex, comparing the keycode is enough.

```js
function filterNumericKey(e) {
    var c = e.keyCode;
    return (c >= 48 && c <= 57) || // "0" .. "9"
            c === 32 ||            // " "
            c === 40 ||            // "("
            c === 41 ||            // ")"
            c === 45 ||            // "-"
            c === 46;              // "."
}

$(function(){
    $('#p_zip').on('keypress', filterNumericKey);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="p_zip">
```

---

Notes

1. The following is an anti-pattern, in any language, not just JS:

   ```
   if (booleanCondition) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
   ```

   Just use `return booleanCondition;` directly instead.
2. If you want to use `new RegExp()` instead of a regex literal, you

   - *must not* use forward slashes to delimit your expression
   - *must* escape any backslashes, just like you would do in any other JavaScript string
3. **Beware** that both solutions will not check text that is pasted or dropped on the input element. You might want to write checks for that as well.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, always returning false. Wait, I'll create a fiddle.

Comment: Is this correct? This returns true for the input "abc". Instead of testing that there are no non-allowed characters, you are testing that there is at least one non-allowed character, I think. I think you're missing a `^` in the character set.

Comment: @torazaburo Oh, misread the requirement as "do not want to allow", instead of "only want to allow". Fixed answer, thanks.

Comment: Why fix it that way? It would be simpler to do `!/[^0-9.() -]/.test(str)` and dispense with the anchors and quanitifer.

Comment: Well, `^[0-9.() -]*$` easily allows for different length requirements (`*`, `+`, `{2,}` etc) and `[^0-9.() -]` does not. If zero is an acceptable input length, it's of course equivalent.

Comment: Added fiddle in my question

Comment: The color is changing..but I want to disable input of that character...at present I'm able to type alphabets too which I don't want to

Comment: @asprin I was about to say that you need to cancel the `keypress` event, not the `keyup` event, but I see that you have found out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I was making a rookie mistake. I needed to `return false` on `keypress` event instead of `keyup`. And I was also taking the `value` of the textbox into account instead of the `event` object.

```
function isNumber(e) {
    var theEvent = e || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (key.length == 0) return;
    var regex = /^[0-9\.\b\(\) -]+$/;
    if (!regex.test(key)) {        
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return regex.test(key);` Also, since you are using jQuery, you can actually remove that cross-browser boilerplate code.

Comment: (Also check out my revised and expanded answer.)